# "notice" con cierre automático con Bootstrap y Rails

Tags: bootstrap, ruby-on-rails

¿Alguien sabe cómo hacer para que la sección de notice que Rails coloca en las vistas se cierre automáticamente después de cierto tiempo?

Después de dar update en mi controlador redirecciono a index.html.erb, donde tengo mi notice con un alert de Bootrsap:

```
<% if notice %>
  <p id="notice" class="alert alert-success" role="alert"><%= notice %></p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No es necesario ocupar bootstrap, ni siquiera javascript. Con CSS puro, puedes lograr el efecto:

```css
.alert{
    -moz-animation: cssAnimation 0s ease-in 5s forwards;
    /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: cssAnimation 0s ease-in 5s forwards;
    /* Safari y Chrome */
    -o-animation: cssAnimation 0s ease-in 5s forwards;
    /* Opera */
    animation: cssAnimation 0s ease-in 5s forwards;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes cssAnimation {
    to {
        width:0;
        height:0;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes cssAnimation {
    to {
        width:0;
        height:0;
        visibility:hidden;
    }
}
```

```html
<p class="alert" >
Esto es una alerta que se va en 5 segundos
</p>
```

En caso de que quieras un efecto de fading, puedes probar con:

```css
.alert {
    -webkit-animation: cssAnimation 3s forwards; 
    animation: cssAnimation 3s forwards;
}
@keyframes cssAnimation {
    0%   {opacity: 1;}
    90%  {opacity: 1;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes cssAnimation {
    0%   {opacity: 1;}
    90%  {opacity: 1;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
}
```

```html
<p class="alert" >
Esta se va en 3 segundos y con fade out
</p>
```

Comment: Muy buen aporte, aunque un poco complejo para mi gusto.  Sin embargo, por haberte tomado el tiempo para recrear un ejemplo completo marcaré la respuesta como la mejor.  Gracias.

Comment: Si, puede verse más complejo, pero en términos de rendimiento, es superior a cualquier uso de js, más aún con jQuery (que de por cierto, cada vez va más en desuso). Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Puuedes usar jquery para ocultar el parrafo pasado un tiempo:

```js
$(".alert-success" ).fadeOut(3000);
```

Comment: Fue lo que primero pensé, pero me salía error de que no se reconoce la función $.  Parece que el error iba por otro lado.  En este post me dieron respuesta a eso:  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/316364/c%c3%b3mo-ejecutar-funciones-javascript-personalizadas-en-rails-6/316457#316457

Comment: Si te da error el "$" será porque no estás usando jquery, cosa que te recomiendo altamente para hacer el fadeOut. Sino puedes hacerlo con javascript, pero tendrás que poner mucho más código

Comment: Sí lo uso, pero Webpack no me deja usar $ así.