# Cómo ejecutar funciones javascript personalizadas en Rails 6

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Con la llegada de Webpacker a Ruby On Rails no encuentro la manera de utilizar mis funciones de Javascript.

Tengo un archivo llamado app-globals.js con una función para probar:

```
function alertas() {
   alert("PRUEBA")
}
```

Luego la quiero usar en una de mis vistas:

```
<%= button_tag 'Button', type: 'button', onClick: 'alertas()' %>
```

Pero cuando presiono el botón me muestra este error en la consola del navegador:

> ReferenceError: alertas is not defined

He probado de varias maneras:

1. Coloqué el archivo app-globals.js en "app/javascript" y en
   "app/javascript/packs/application.js" coloqué
   require("app-globals").
2. Moví app-globals.js a "app/javascript/packs" y quité el
   require("app-globals") de application.js.
3. Coloqué esto en application.html.erb:

Con cualquiera de los dos casos sigue saliendo error.

Alguna ayuda por favor.

Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si te fijas en cómo webpacker genera tu archivo js, verás que es algo como:

```
  !*** ./app/javascript/packs/application.js ***!
  \*********************************************/
/*! no static exports found */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

  function alertas() {
    alert("PRUEBA")
  }
```

O sea, tu función está definida dentro de otra función, lo cual es inaccesible desde el entorno global de js.
Una manera de poder saltarte esta restricción, sería que definieras tu función globalmente con:

```js
// Esto es, simplificadamente, lo que hace webpacker con las funciones
// definidas, incluído el .call(this) al final
(function(module, exports) {
  window.alerta1 = function() {
    document.body.innerHTML += "esta debe funcionar";
  };
  function alerta2() {
    document.body.innerHTML += "esta no";
  }
}.call(this));

alerta1();
alerta2();
```